# How to call a 'self' property from prepareForSegue:?

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, ios6, nsarray

I have a `@property` in the model class of my app that will call `prepareForSegue:`. It's publicly declared like this in my `CalculatorBrain` class.

```
@property (readonly) id program.
```

The getter looks like this:

```
- (id)program
{
    return [self.programStack copy];
}
```

In case you need to know, `programStack` is a `NSMutableArray @property` of `CalculatorBrain` that stores all the operations and operands that the user inputs.

The controller of the calculator is `CalculatorViewController`, and I have a private property for the brain (a CalculatorBrain) for it. In all my CalculatorViewController methods I can perfectly call `self.brain.program`. But when I try to call this getters from my `prepareForSegue:` method this returns an empty array. Here's an example of a method that I have in CalculatorViewController that can perfectly call self.brain.program:

```
- (IBAction)enterPressed
{
    [self.brain pushOperand:[self.display.text doubleValue]];
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = NO;

    // update history label
    NSArray *stack = self.brain.program; //This is to test self.brain.program
    self.history.text = [CalculatorBrain descriptionOfProgram:self.brain.program];
}
```

If we set a breakpoint in the self.history.text... line check the values, here's what we get:

[image]

And it's correct, at tha moment the program had 2 objects.

Now here's my `prepareForSegue:` method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Graph"]) {
        GraphingCalcViewController *newController = segue.destinationViewController;
        // send program to newController
        NSArray *stack = self.brain.program; //This is to test self.brain.program
        newController.program = self.brain.program;
    }
}
```

If we set a breakpoint in the newController.program... line, here's what we get:

[image]

Both snapshots are from the same run. So my question is, why is the value of self.brain.program different when prepareForSegue: calls it? Maybe it's a very dumb mistake, but I just can't spot it. I'd appreciate a bit of help here. I'm pretty new to iOS development.

**UPDATE:** The problem appears to be with the programStack. It is somehow `niling` out before  the `prepareForSegue:` method comes into play. So when this one runs, we get fresh new empty programStack. Some other method (not mine, as far as I know) is clearing it out.

Anyone has any idea of what might be clearing my property here? I have both `strong` pointers to the `brain` (CalculatorBrain * in the CalculatorViewController) and the `programStack` (NSMutableArray * in the CalculatorBrain).

Comment: Please post the public declaration of newController.program in GraphingCalcViewController.h and also Change id to NSMutableArray. there is no point at having it declared as id.

Answer (score 0):

The getter for program uses the copy method on your `programStack` for assignment, and that requires `programStack` to obey the `NSCopying` protocol. hIs `programStack` really just `NSMutableArray`? Because that does obey `NSCopying` and should work. Try taking out the copy?

Update: is the value of `self.brain` changing between your two calls?

Comment: He's doing cs193p. It's just a normal NSMutableArray. My graphing calculator works fine. My `prepareForSegue` in the assignment calculator I built works fine, and it's virtually identical. :\

Comment: Because it's a copy, if one does [stack addObject:something] in the main body of the program, that produces a different result from [self.brain.program addObject:something]. Is that happening somewhere?

Comment: @Metabble is right. I'm doing cs193p and it is just a normal NSMutableArray. Now, emrys57, I can't send an 'addObject:' message to any of those, because stack is a simple test NSArray, and the program property of the brain is 'readonly' and it doesn't even have an instance variable to store something in. It's job is to return a copy of the NSMutableArray programStack.

Metabble: So your GraphController get's a correct version of the program with the same prepareForSegue method I did? This is creeping me out :\

Comment: The only difference I can see is the fact that I nested into a smaller space. `if([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"graph"]){ [segue.destinationViewController setProgram:self.brain.program]; }` is all mine contains. The problem probably exists somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

My code for CS193 was very similar, the main difference that I saw was that I passed a copy of the program rather than a reference to the same object.  So try this:

```
newController.program = [self.brain.program copy];
```

Comment: Just tried it and it didn't work :( However I did find out something. My `programStack` is somehow clearing out before time. I added some details in the update to the post above.

Comment: I would try adding an NSLog statement to the setter for your program property so you can see when it's getting called.